# java.lang.NullPointerException in CreateNamedQuery

Tags: jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception, ejb, resultset

I have the following code which is resulting in a `java.lang.NullPointerException`:

```
List results = em.createNamedQuery("User.findByUserName").setParameter("userName", username).getResultList();
```

User is the entity bean, which contains:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findByUserName", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.userName = :userName"),
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: show us the stacktrace of the exception!

Comment: I am not getting the stack trace of the exception . The webpage stays in the same page.

Comment: You should be getting the stacktrace *somewhere*, for example in the server logs. Unless you've manually caught the exception and not used `e.printStackTrace()`. In that case you should fix that.

Comment: I meant the stack trace that we see on  the localhost. In the server log, it says INFO: Caught exception in UserFacade java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: Probably EntityManager (em)  is null. Check that. Your query is right.

Comment: yes u r right, em is null. How do i go about it now?

Answer (score 1):

A method `getResultList()` doesn't throw `NullPointerException` (it returns empty list if there's no match), so I'm guessing that it should be one of the following:

- you didn't inject/initialize `EntityManager em` (did you forget
  `@PersistenceContext` annotation?)
- String `username` is null

In case of EntityManager null, check whether you have persistence.xml file (it's mandatory!). It should look like:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="OEMSPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>ADD JNDI NAME OF YOUR DATASOURCE, e.g. jdbc/sample</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: I do have the @PersistenceContext(unitName = "OEMSPU"). String username is not null either as I have printed it out to check.

Comment: Please check in your code whether `em` is null or not prior to calling named query.

Comment: Yes, I do have the persistence.xml file.                            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="OEMSPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>OEMS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

Comment: You're missing <provider> tag, and alternatively, throw out the `(unitName = "OEMSPU")` part, i.e. just use `@PersistenceContext` annotation without any parameters.

Comment: MAde the changes u told, still the same

Comment: Does injection works in case of your class, i.e. are you using this annotation in container-handled class (EJB, servlet..) or in POJO?

Comment: I am using the annotation in EJB : session beans

Comment: Huh..the last thing that comes to my mind is that JDBC resource `OEMS` doesn't exist or it's not deployed on your cluster/standalone instance.

Comment: Which application server are you using?

Comment: I had not injected the EJB in managed bean, thats why I was getting the error. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try making it a Stateless Bean by adding @Stateless annotation above the public class. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This can come about when your psql is referencing an entity property name. I was doing something like `:param.user = x.user` in my psql, but trying to grab the property "user" from a param (which hasn't been passed in yet when createQuery runs) was giving me the NPE. I wish this sort of thing were possible, though..